# Group_Concat used in mysql cursor returning wrong result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, mariadb

The following code should produce 3 entries for csv2 ... however 6 entries are produced.

Why is that? The code is in progress.

**Creation Code:**

```
Create table testing(
  idString varchar(20),
  region varchar(20)
);

insert into testing values("abcdefg","123456");
insert into testing values("bcdefgh","123456");
insert into testing values("cdefghi","123456");
insert into testing values("defghij","456789");
insert into testing values("efghijk","456789");
insert into testing values("fghijkl","456789");
```

**Code to Run:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_split`;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getCombinations`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp` (
  `col` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `result` (
  `col1` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY;


CREATE PROCEDURE getCombinations()
  BEGIN

    DECLARE countInt INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE csv varchar(100);
    DECLARE region varchar(100);
    DECLARE v_last_row_fetched INT;
    declare v_counter int unsigned default 1;

    DECLARE counter cursor for
      select  * from ( select region as region,
                              count(distinct idString) as countInt,
                              group_concat(idString) as csv
                          from testing
                          group by region ) temp;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET  v_last_row_fetched=1;
    SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT');

    delete from result;
    open counter;
    c1_loop: loop
      fetch counter into region , countInt, csv ;


      IF  v_last_row_fetched=1 THEN LEAVE c1_loop; END IF;

      #DEBUG STATEMENT HERE - 6 values instead of two displayed for csv3
      select csv as csv3;
      LEAVE c1_loop;

    end loop c1_loop;
    close counter;

  END;

DELIMITER ;

CALL getCombinations();
SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT');
```

Comment: `SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';` is pretty unsafe because it turns off the other sql modes you may need... beter is to use `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT');`

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Thanks for that. Any idea why all elements are being concatenated instead of three? it seems almost like the group by is being ignored.

Comment: What's the point of running the code in a loop if you have an unconditional `leave c1_loop;` statement?

Comment: @Barmar I am debugging. Obviously the code isn't complete. It's just that group_concat is concatenating all values and not doing the `group by region`. I didn't spend the time to remove all the stuff I will actually use after solving the current issue.

Comment: It would make it easier for us to help you if you didn't post so much irrelevant code, it's hard to know where to look.

Comment: @Barmar Updated thanks! . Problem line is below `#DEBUG STATEMENT HERE - 6 values instead of two displayed for csv3`

Comment: This is definitely weird, it's ignoring `GROUP BY region`

Comment: I see the problem, you have a local variable named `region`.

Comment: @Barmar Hah.. Oops :( . I sort of worked around it by using a view 5 minutes ago but this definitely makes sense. Silly mistake. If you answer I will obviously upvote and accept. Thanks!

Comment: Show us the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a local variable named `region`, and this is being used in `GROUP BY region` rather than the column. So it's as if you'd written `GROUP BY null`, so everything is grouped together.

Change the name of the `region` variable and it will work. In general, avoid using variables that have the same names as your table columns, it often causes problems.